# c compiler source code for compiler construction

Tags: compilers

Could anyone tell me from where could I get the c compiler source code.In particular the lexical analyzer for c.I searched the web but no links show how a compiler is defined.

Comment: This is not Google, and source code is not ontopic here as such.

Comment: I notice that you have had multiple questions closed. Please familiarized yourself with our scope (e.g. via [faq]) and browse through some questions in order to find out which kind of questions we like.

Answer (score 1):

search the web:  "c compiler" source

By the way, You can find source code for any [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) or [open-source software](http://opensource.org/), and a licence allowing you to use it freely.

C being the implementation language for Unix, I would expect it to have been one of the first pieces of software with available source, and a [copyleft licence](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/).

When searching the web for the source code of a piece of sofware, look for these types of licences (without a licence you are not allowed to use the source code anyway).
 [Creative Commons licences](https://creativecommons.org/) will generally do too, and non copylefted free licences such as [BSD licences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses). All these terms are usually useful keywords to find software with source code available.

Comment: Please don't encourage posters of offtopic questions.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry. The question looked so silly, I forgot it was off topic. That is for my first sentence. Then some old reflexes took over. Maybe it can be moved to a more appropriate place. Should I delete?

Comment: Nah, it might be helpful to someone (until the whole question is deleted automatically).